# How do I setup WinMerge to show compare on an explorer context menu?

Tags: context-menu, winmerge

I'm using WinMerge version 2.16.6.0. I want to setup a Compare option in File Explorer context menu. I have done this before but had to re-install my system and now can't remember how I did it. Checking the help it says to use the "Shell Integration page" but that page does not exist. The help also says "Enabled: Replaces the WinMerge shortcut in the Explorer context menu with Compare shortcuts" so I know it should exist. During the install process I selected "Enable Explorer Context Menu Integration" but that didn't add the "compare" item. It does put a shortcut to WinMerge in the context menu but it doesn't add "compare".

Does anyone know how to get "compare" to show up on the File Explorer context?

Answer (score 4):

With this version of WinMerge (I have it here), it has changed from earlier versions. Right click on the file use Windows Explorer. The context menu shows WinMerge. Click on this and first file preloads in the WinMerge dialogue Window. Then in the second line, browse for the second file. I find this to be easiest.

You can also look at WinMerge, Edit, Options and the Shell Integration settings shows Context Options. I have the first one checked (selected). You can then enable the second option.That gives you Compare and Compare To on the Context menu which is like it used to be. Works perfectly

Comment: Thanks, the second option you mentioned fixed it.

Comment: Thanks John, just to clarify the commands   added to the content menu are 'Select left' and I would then use 'compare'. Also you do the added option of 'Select middle' for three way compares.

Comment: I tend to just compare two files at one time.